# Postgresql alternative for trigger in multiple-row insert

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.6

I have a table where the values of different variables are stored. Basically, it is a table of the form data_table (timestamp, variable, value). One of the variables represents a state value.

Certain values of this state variable represent system errors. I would like to create an error_log table to easily visualize the times where errors start and end. It would be a table of the form error_log (error, start_time, end_time).

I could do so with an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` with the following pseudocode:

```
new_state = NEW.value
old_state = (select value from data_table where variable = state_variable order by timestamp desc limit 1)

if(old_state != error_state and new_state == error_state)
 insert error in table error_log

elif (old_state == error_state and new_state != error_state)
 update error in error_log to inclue end time
```

This works fine except in the case where several state values are inserted at the same time, which sometimes happens in my system. In this case, the function is triggered once for every row but old_value is the same for all of them, the state value that was stored before the multiple-row insert query.

I understand that this is the expected behavior of the trigger, as mentioned in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28283/postgresql-after-for-each-row-triggers-dont-actually-execute-after-each-row), so I would like to know it if there is a way of implementing the creation of the error_log table in a different way.

- Is it possible to implement it without using a trigger?
- Is is possible to retrieve the value in the previous insert somehow?
- Is it possible to send one state value to the trigger of the next row?
- Is it possible to check all inserted values executing the trigger at statement-level instead of row-level?

Comment: The only way to reliably see the previous row would be to serialize all inserts. Do you really want to pay that price? It is bad for concurrency.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Not really, I was hoping for a different option

Comment: Perhaps you should think of different ways to achieve your goal, like a job that scans older table entries. I'd say that a trigger is too early to be able to collect that information.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If I implemented something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837511/how-to-properly-emulate-statement-level-triggers-with-access-to-data-in-postgres), I could solve the issue for multiple-row inserts by checking them all in a statement-level trigger. However, I suppose there would still be issues in case of parallel statements...

Comment: Yes, [there are always race conditions](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/) with concurrent modifications.